# Variable from another void

Tags: c#, variables, void

I am a novice programmer (c #) and I stuck. I do not know why the compiler does not see the variable from another void. About a week ago in another program it worked and now does not want to.  I was looking for a similar problem but I have not found.

```
public void Gridcommandevent(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs ev)
{
    int index;
    if (ev.CommandName == "Update")
    {
       index = Convert.ToInt32(ev.CommandArgument);
    }
}

protected void GridView3_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{   
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DGCodLocConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Parts SET [LastModified] = '" + Permit + "' WHERE PartsID = '" + index + "'", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

I want the `index` variable to the `SqlCommand` object.

By the way. Is this good code? It will be works ? i want to varible 'Permit' insert in to cell [LastModified] after updating data(row) in gridview.

It seems that this not works as it should :( I mean, variable 'index' is fine now, but code is just broken.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: consider using a parameterized query to not be too open for sql-injection ...! http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: But there is no textbox

Comment: that doesn't really matter, though. name it consistency or whatever, but the very first moment you quit using parameters is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your variable outside your void, so you can access it from all members. **As you have it it is only visible to `Gridcommandevent`**.

```
int index;
public void Gridcommandevent(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs ev)
{
    if (ev.CommandName == "Update")
    {
       index = Convert.ToInt32(ev.CommandArgument);
    }
}

protected void GridView3_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{   
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DGCodLocConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Parts SET [LastModified] = '" + Permit + "' WHERE PartsID = '" + index + "'", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
}
```

As per `Andreas Niedermair` suggestion, and since you say you are a novice programmer, you should have a look at this **[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)**.

Comment: no no no ... the OP is obviously an absolute beginner. the op asked "why" and not "how" ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Look at the last line of his question. He wants a way to access the variable.

Comment: ...  and (s)he does not know why it is not accesible from the other method ... given the skill-level you should at least mention **scopes**

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Since you already covered this in your comment at the question, are you ok, if i use the link in my answer? For what is worth, you are right and i should get a bit deeper in variable visibility.

Comment: Well. my mistake. I just watching on this code long time. Thanks for answers

Comment: I am absolutely OK with this - hey, it's common property ;)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I know, but still i do not like mentioning the exact same thing as someone else without at least notifying him.